# How to print selected range of a sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, printing

Can someone help me to print a selected range of cells in a current sheet in Google Sheets?

Comment: what do you mean by "print"?

Comment: good question. Sorry I missed it. Print can be 
- open print window of google sheets
- download PDF with selected range
both options fit well

Comment: @MarchukAnton Please edit that into the body of your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I solved the issue with the creating hyperlink that downloads selected range with all the parameters. For my purposes download PDF even better. So instead of script-button, I placed a hyperlink to a cell and it downloads PDF perfectly.

Comment: Can you give source to make links to download a selected range or tab as pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need a script, tho.

- select the range of cells you want to print
- press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`P`</kbd>**
- select **Select cells**
- and proceed printing

[image]

Comment: this would be too simple but I need a script that I will assign to a button